# Is the map-Parameter of the UMN-mapserver conform to the OGC WMS-specification?

Tags: specifications, mapserver, umn-mapserver, umn, ogc

Say you have a mapserver-url like this: http://host/cgi-bin/mapserv?MAP=/path/to/mapfile.map&

Is a WMS specified in this way conform to the OGC WMS-specification? Some say the map-parameter is a vendor-specific parameter, but you also could see it as part of the URL-prefix for this service (ending with ? or & as specified, it's an & in this case). What do you think, is that compatible to the specification or not?

Comment: lordy... are you going for the tumbleweed badge? :)

Comment: I ran into the problem in reality. We are in dispute with a 'partner' over this topic. As I cannot show a stackoverflow-discussion to resolve this topic I hope I get good hints about the interpretation of the relevant parts of the specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OGC WMS [1.1.1](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=1081) (Section 6.2.2)and [1.3.0](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=4756) (Section 6.3.3) specifications are fairly clear regarding this topic:

> An Online Resource URL intended for
>   HTTP GET requests  is in fact only a
>   URL prefix to which additional
>   parameters are appended in order to
>   construct a valid Operation request. A
>   URL prefix is defined in accordance
>   with IETF RFC 2396 as a string
>   including, in order, the scheme
>   (“http” or “https”), Internet Protocol
>   hostname or numeric address, optional
>   port number, path, mandatory question
>   mark “?”, **and optional string
>   comprising one or more server-specific
>   parameters ending in an ampersand
>   “&”**.

As long as the online resource URL finishes with an "&", it should adhere to the WMS specification